# Sum Query with ExecuteScalar Method

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with C# winforms, trying to do a sum query and I used the `ExecuteScalar`  method to check if that worked. Im showing the "sum" in a `MessageBox`.

My problem: the query does't work, because the sum in the messagebox is still 0.

My method:

```
string Name = salesdetails.CmbEmployeeName.Text;
        int sum = 0;
        string connStr = @"Data Source=............................";
        string Query = ("SELECT SUM(PriceOrder) FROM tblOrdersFromCustomers WHERE CustomerID=N'" + Name + "'");

        using (SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();

                sum = (int)cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar();
            }

            catch
            {
            }

        }
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sum: {0}", sum));
```

Comment: Is your CustomerID column in the table a string or is it an id and you should be filtering on a different column?

Comment: @GrantWinney The `N` is outside the quotes.

Comment: `Sum()` does not return an integer so you probably get an `InvalidCastException` in c#. Try `sum = (int)(decimal)cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: My CustomerID is nvarchar(50)

Comment: @Silvermind It's still zero

Comment: Assuming youve tried the sql direct on the database and it returned a value, Try changing sum to an object and removing the cast, see if you actually get a value back

Comment: Try running the query manually and make sure you connect to the same database, check the textbox value for characters like `\n`, etc.

Comment: I did all........
Is my querry good?

Answer (score 0):

First I think your query has issue

i.e. Seems your table name is incorrect.

Shouldn't it be `tblOrders` rather than      `tblOrdersFromCustomers`

Use [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using(reader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        sum  = reader[0]!=DBNull.Value?Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]):0; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes, what the issue you have? check whether your `Query` is fine?

Comment: @user3393134 : Probably something wrong with your query!! Put a bullet point after you build the Query and try run that directly in database?

Comment: @user3393134: is it correct `CustomerID=N'" + Name` ?? Or should it be `CustomerID='" + Name` ??

Comment: Ok, what is the value of `salesdetails.CmbEmployeeName.Text`?? can you try running `SELECT SUM(PriceOrder) FROM tblOrdersFromCustomers WHERE CustomerID=value` directly in database and see? maybe you need to `salesdetails.CmbEmployeeName.Text.Trim()`

Comment: Im tried simple query like :   string Query = ("SELECT SUM(PriceOrder) FROM tblOrdersFromCustomers"); and its still zero

Comment: @user3393134: Think your table name is incorrect!! Is it `tblOrdersFromCustomers` or `tblOrders`?? Updated the answer!!!

Comment: @user3393134: Do you actually get any result when you do `SELECT SUM(PriceOrder) FROM tblOrdersFromCustomers` directly in database?

Comment: I have a lot of Orders in that table but when I do SELECT SUM(PriceOrder) FROM tblOrdersFromCustomers the SUM is still zero, I'm really don't understand why.....

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = Convert.ToInt32(cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: its writing to me: Cannot convert type  'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to 'int'.

Comment: @user3393134: no it does not throw error, are you sure?